# What does "Automatic cleaning is not available/necessary with this backend" mean? (for memcache )

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached

I have installed the memcache in my php zend code.  it seems no error.  but there is a warning in the log saying

```
Zend_Cache_Core::save() / automatic cleaning is not available/necessary with this backend.
```

what does it really mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zend Cache supports different backend storage devices including memcache, file storage, APC, etc.

Each one has its own implementation - as you can see in the Zend library - and apparently the memcache implementation doesn't support automatic cleaning.

You can see the code here:  Zend\Cache\Backend\Memcached.php

Comment: so, does it causing any problem?  or will it make memcache doesnt' work?

Comment: To me it appears to be benign and that it's more of the "not necessary" rather than the "not available" in this case.

Comment: Memcaced is (i quess) like this:
"here you have 10MBs of space, fill it with cached data. When you run out of space, clear the oldest one"

Answer (score 4):

Well, i'm a bit late, but here is the solution :

place "automatic_cleaning_factor" => 0 in your Zend_Cache::factory frontend's options

Comment: The log entry mentions backend - is that what you meant?